# Identifying if a datetime from one dataframe is within an hour after another dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, A and B:

A

```
abc|def|datetime            |
1  |55 |2016-01-28 00:00:00 |
2  |53 |2016-01-28 00:30:00 |
3  |11 |2016-01-28 02:00:00 |
```

B

```
efg|hij|datetime            |
4  |ch |2016-01-28 00:11:00 |
5  |jw |2016-01-28 11:30:00 |
6  |q1 |2016-01-28 07:00:00 |
```

I Want to add a true false column to the end of A if a value B is within an hour after. And also a column that shows a value B is within an hour before.

A output:

```
abc|def|datetime            |After|Before|
1  |55 |2016-01-28 00:00:00 |  0  |  1   |
2  |53 |2016-01-28 00:30:00 |  1  |  0   |
3  |11 |2016-01-28 02:00:00 |  0  |  0   |
```

I have tried using `library(lubridate):

```
for(i in seq(nrow(B))){
  for(j in seq(nrow(A))){
    if(A$datetime[j] %in% seq(B$datetime[i],B$datetime[i] + hours(1))){
      A$After[j] = 1
    }
  }
}
```

But i can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Additional Information:

The dataframes do not line up, I am wanting to identify if there are any cases in B which are within an hour After or Before A. If this is the case then add 1 to the column. eg:

`4  |ch |2016-01-28 00:11:00 |` is after `1  |55 |2016-01-28 00:00:00 |`

`4  |ch |2016-01-28 00:11:00 |` is before `2  |53 |2016-01-28 00:30:00 |`

B is an event and I am wanting to identify that event in relation to A.

Comment: How comes for the second row it is the same day with 23hrs:30 mins after yet you have a 1?

Comment: Can't get it to work how? What are you getting?

Comment: `Error in seq.POSIXt(B$Datetime[i], B$Datetime[i] +  : 
  exactly two of 'to', 'by' and 'length.out' / 'along.with' must be specified` @camille

Comment: @Onyambu as 00:30:00 is after 00:11:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited question based on extra info. In this case it is slightly easier. You can use functions from lubridate to find our if a datetime falls between 2 dates. You need 2 functions for this. First creating an interval object and secondly using the `%within%` function to find out if a date falls in an interval.

In the code below I created 2 interval objects, Before and After. To check if each value of B falls in one of the intervals we need to run a loop.

```
library(lubridate)

after_interval <- as.interval(3600, A$datetime)
# flip interval to get lower date first in the interval
before_interval <- int_flip(as.interval(-3600, A$datetime)) 

for(i in seq_along(length(B$datetime))) {
  After <- B$datetime[i] %within% after_interval
  After = as.integer(After)
  if(i == 1){
    AfterLoop = After
  } else {
      AfterLoop = AfterLoop + After}

  Before <- B$datetime[i] %within% before_interval 
  Before = as.integer(Before)
  if(i == 1){
    BeforeLoop = Before
  } else {
      BeforeLoop = BeforeLoop + Before}
}
A$After <- AfterLoop
A$Before <-BeforeLoop
A
  abc def            datetime After Before
1   1  55 2016-01-28 00:00:00  TRUE  FALSE
2   2  53 2016-01-28 00:30:00 FALSE   TRUE
3   3  11 2016-01-28 02:00:00 FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: The two dataframes contain different information, I'll add some more to the question description.

Comment: @MaskedMonkey, changed the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to work well, is the 3600 seconds in an hour? does this factor in calender time, eg leap years?

Comment: yes 3600 seconds is an hour :-). R keeps track of leap years and by extension so do the lubridate functions. just deduct 1 hr from "2016-03-01 00:00:10" and you will get "2016-02-29 23:00:10"

Comment: Great, as an extra question, both of my dataframes are spatial, i can create a buffer of one, how would I incorporate that the buffer of B, using package `sf`, `buffer = st_buffer(B[i], 500)` and the objects A intersect as an extra restriction to making after and before true?

Comment: I'm attempting:   `A$Before <- B$Datetime[i] %within% before_interval & st_intersects(B[i], A)` but getting `Error in Ops.sgbp(B$Datetime[i] %within% before_interval,  : 
  only ! operator is supported for sgbp objects`

Comment: @MaskedMonkey, hmm, no idea without having a reproducible example. I can't just turn A and B into sf class. I think it would be best if you could create a new question with A and B as the data.frames with spatial objects or something like that. Then someone will answer it.

Comment: Looking further into this solution, It appears that the loop overwrites, so that only the last result is given.